# Reading XML Response from envelope event notification

Tags: c#, asp.net, docusignapi

In my MakeEnvelope method, I have added an event notification as follows:

```
var en = new EventNotification
        {
            Url = "<Listener URL>",
            LoggingEnabled = "true",
            RequireAcknowledgment = "true",
            EnvelopeEvents = new List<EnvelopeEvent>
            {
                new EnvelopeEvent
                {
                    EnvelopeEventStatusCode = "Completed",
                    IncludeDocuments = "true"
                },
                new EnvelopeEvent
                {
                    EnvelopeEventStatusCode = "Delivered",
                    IncludeDocuments = "false"
                },
                new EnvelopeEvent
                {
                    EnvelopeEventStatusCode = "Sent",
                    IncludeDocuments = "false"
                }
            }
        }; 
envelopeDefinition.EventNotification = en;
```

I get the following XML response (I removed the Names and Emails, and changed the Guids):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><DocuSignEnvelopeInformation xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0"><EnvelopeStatus><RecipientStatuses><RecipientStatus><Type>Signer</Type><Email>someEmail@email.com</Email><UserName>SomeUserName</UserName><RoutingOrder>1</RoutingOrder><Sent>2021-04-28T14:14:41.163</Sent><Delivered>2021-04-28T14:14:54.997</Delivered><Signed>2021-04-28T14:14:59.73</Signed><DeclineReason xsi:nil="true" /><Status>Completed</Status><RecipientIPAddress>IP Address</RecipientIPAddress><ClientUserId>The ClientId</ClientUserId><CustomFields /><TabStatuses><TabStatus><TabType>SignHere</TabType><Status>Signed</Status><XPosition>938</XPosition><YPosition>1169</YPosition><TabLabel>Sign Here</TabLabel><TabName>SignHere</TabName><TabValue /><DocumentID>3</DocumentID><PageNumber>1</PageNumber></TabStatus></TabStatuses><AccountStatus>Active</AccountStatus><RecipientId>f571daaf-cd2c-4fge-a72e-d32277929305</RecipientId></RecipientStatus><RecipientStatus><Type>Signer</Type><Email>anotherEmail.Email.com</Email><UserName>Another Name</UserName><RoutingOrder>1</RoutingOrder><Sent>2021-04-28T14:14:41.503</Sent><DeclineReason xsi:nil="true" /><Status>Sent</Status><RecipientIPAddress /><CustomFields /><TabStatuses><TabStatus><TabType>SignHere</TabType><Status>Active</Status><XPosition>196</XPosition><YPosition>1169</YPosition><TabLabel>Sign Here</TabLabel><TabName>SignHere</TabName><TabValue /><DocumentID>3</DocumentID><PageNumber>1</PageNumber></TabStatus></TabStatuses><AccountStatus>Active</AccountStatus><RecipientId>1eb9d346-33ae-4444-b5f1-be30f8bcf041</RecipientId></RecipientStatus></RecipientStatuses><TimeGenerated>2021-04-28T14:15:03.3011225</TimeGenerated><EnvelopeID>3c9281c7-3345-44ac-9c4f-3d39274c49f4</EnvelopeID><Subject>Please sign this document</Subject><UserName>User Name</UserName><Email>Users Email Address Here</Email><Status>Sent</Status><Created>2021-04-28T14:14:40.41</Created><Sent>2021-04-28T14:14:41.557</Sent><ACStatus>Original</ACStatus><ACStatusDate>2021-04-28T14:14:40.41</ACStatusDate><ACHolder>Account Holders name</ACHolder><ACHolderEmail>Account Holders Email</ACHolderEmail><ACHolderLocation>DocuSign</ACHolderLocation><SigningLocation>Online</SigningLocation><SenderIPAddress>Senders IP Address</SenderIPAddress><EnvelopePDFHash /><CustomFields /><AutoNavigation>true</AutoNavigation><EnvelopeIdStamping>true</EnvelopeIdStamping><AuthoritativeCopy>false</AuthoritativeCopy><DocumentStatuses><DocumentStatus><ID>3</ID><Name>PG Document</Name><TemplateName /><Sequence>1</Sequence></DocumentStatus></DocumentStatuses></EnvelopeStatus></DocuSignEnvelopeInformation>
```

I was having issues parsing the response, so I created a console application to parse the xml string, and using the response xml shown above. The following is the code that I used to parse.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string strXML = GetXML();

        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.LoadXml(strXML);

        string xpath = "DocuSignEnvelopeInformation/EnvelopeStatus";

        var nodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes(xpath);

        foreach (XmlNode childrenNode in nodes)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(childrenNode.SelectSingleNode("//status").Value);
        }

        Console.Read();

    }
```

nodes is always empty.

What am I missing here?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it to work by using the namespace it was using.

```
var ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);
ns.AddNamespace("docusign", "http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0");
var envelopeId = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//docusign:EnvelopeID", ns);
var status = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//docusign:Status", ns);
```

I changed the method and I am able to get the values:

```
 Request.InputStream.Position = 0;
 var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
 xmlDoc.Load(Request.InputStream);

 var ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);
 ns.AddNamespace("docusign", "http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0");
 var envelopeId = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//docusign:EnvelopeID", ns);
 var status = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//docusign:EnvelopeStatus/docusign:Status", ns);

 if (envelopeId == null || String.IsNullOrEmpty(envelopeId.InnerText) || status == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(status.InnerText)) return;

 if (status.InnerText.ToLower() == "completed")
 {
    // Update the Document Status
       var extra = _uow.JobExtraRepository.GetByEnvelopeId(envelopeId.InnerText);
       extra.StatusId = (int)ExtraJobStatus.Completed;
       Save();
       var docBytes = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//docusign:docBytes", ns);
 }
```